# How to make X number of random sets of 3 from pandas column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe column that looks like this (roughly 200 rows):

```
col1
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

I want to create a new dataframe with one column and 15 sets of 3 random combinations of the items in the pandas column. for example:

new_df

```
combinations:
(a,b,c)
(a,c,d)
(a,d,c)
(b,a,d)
(d,a,c)
(a,d,f)
(e,a,f)
(a,f,e)
(b,e,f)
(f,b,e)
(c,b,e)
(b,e,a)
(a,e,f)
(e,f,a)
```

Currently the code I have creates a combination of every possible combination and runs out of memory when I try to append the results to another dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import permutations 

df = pd.read_csv('')
combo = df['col1'].tolist()

perm = permutations(combo,3)
combinations = pd.DataFrame(columns=['combinations'])


list_ = []
for i in  list(perm): 
    combinations['combinations'] = i
    list_.append(i)
```

How do I stop the sets of random combinations to stop at any X number of set or in this case 15 combinations of 3?

Comment: @anon01 no resampling if possible.

Comment: do you want enumerated combinations or random combinations?

Comment: @anon01 random is what i want

Comment: you also say combinations but show permutations.  Which is it?

Comment: @anon01 combinations. I dont care about order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code runs out of memory is specifically because of the part where you call `list(perm)`. doing this will generate **EVERY** permutation possible. So when you do

```
for i in list(perm):
    ...
```

You're telling python to create a list of all permutations, then try to iterate over that list. Instead, if you iterate over the `generator` that calling `permutations` creates (e.g. `for i in perm:` instead of `for i in list(perm):`), you can simply iterate over each permutation without storing them all into memory at once. So if you break your for loop after it loops 15 times, you can achieve your desired result.

However, since we're using `itertools`, we can vastly simplify that logic using `islice` to do the work of getting the first 15 without explicitly writing a `for-loop` and breaking at the 15th iteration:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import permutations, islice

# df = pd.read_csv('')
# combo = df['col1'].tolist()
combo = list("abcefg")

perm_generator = permutations(combo,3)

# get first 15 permutations without running the generator
first_15_perms = islice(perm_generator, 15)

# Store the first 15 permutations into a Series object
series_perms = pd.Series(list(first_15_perms), name="permutations")

print(series_perms)
0     (a, b, c)
1     (a, b, e)
2     (a, b, f)
3     (a, b, g)
4     (a, c, b)
5     (a, c, e)
6     (a, c, f)
7     (a, c, g)
8     (a, e, b)
9     (a, e, c)
10    (a, e, f)
11    (a, e, g)
12    (a, f, b)
13    (a, f, c)
14    (a, f, e)
Name: permutations, dtype: object
```

If you want this as a single column in a `DataFrame` you can use the `to_frame()` method:

```
df_perms = series_perms.to_frame()

print(df_perms)
   permutations
0     (a, b, c)
1     (a, b, e)
2     (a, b, f)
3     (a, b, g)
4     (a, c, b)
5     (a, c, e)
6     (a, c, f)
7     (a, c, g)
8     (a, e, b)
9     (a, e, c)
10    (a, e, f)
11    (a, e, g)
12    (a, f, b)
13    (a, f, c)
14    (a, f, e)
```

Comment: Your explanation is very helpful. However when I run the `series_perms = pd.Series(first_15_perms, name="permutations")`, I get an error `TypeError: object of type 'itertools.islice' has no len()`. I am trying to fix this now

Comment: You can make a temporary list. This is probably a feature in a new version of pandas that allows a generator into a `Series`. Try: `pd.Series(list(first_15_perms), name="permutations")`

Comment: I thought you were interested in a random sequence

Answer (score 1):

While not quite as elegant as the previous answers, If you truly want to create a random sampling of values, not just the first you could also do something along the lines of the following:

```
def newFrame(df: pd.DataFrame, srccol: int, cmbs: int, rows: int) -> pd.DataFrame:
    il = df[srccol].values.tolist()
    nw_df = pd.DataFrame()
    data = []
    for r in range(rows):
        rd =[]
        for ri in range(cmbs):
            rd.append(rnd.choice(il))
        data.append(tuple(rd))
    nw_df['Combinations'] = data
    return nw_df
```

Which when passed a a df as shown in your example in the form of:

```
new_df = newFrame(df, 0, 3, 15)
```

Produces:

```
    Combinations
0   (a, f, e)
1   (a, d, f)
2   (b, c, d)
3   (a, a, d)
4   (f, b, c)
5   (e, b, b)
6   (e, e, d)
7   (c, f, f)
8   (f, e, b)
9   (d, c, e)
```

Comment: Hey just wanted to thank you but I went with the above solution